# Optimizing a method with several loops

Tags: java, loops, optimization

I have a method with several intricated `for` and `if` statements. Ressource usage is not critical yet as the app is still in development but I was wondering if there was some way of optimizing it because it looks awfully heavy.

It all comes down to this: if I have several mapped `Object`, is there a way to check for a value in one (known) field of my objects and if that value is met, update all of them with the same value, without iterating on my map too many times.

Here's the code

```
private Map<Integer, Reservation> CreerMapFax(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session)
{
    // Get the "keys" parameter array from the request
    // and makes an array of integers
    String[] strKeys = request.getParameterValues("keys");
    Integer[] intKeys = new Integer[strKeys.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strKeys.length; i++)
        intKeys[i] = Integer.parseInt(strKeys[i]);

    // Creates Map (1) of the selected bookings that need to be faxed,
    // gets Map (2) of all registered bookings within session
    // and fill (1) with data from (2)
    // by using the keys stored in the array
    boolean mail = true;

    Map<Integer, Booking> mapFax = new HashMap<Integer, Booking>();
    Map<Integer, Booking> bookings=
            (HashMap<Integer, Booking>) session.getAttribute(SESSION_BOOKINGS);

    for (int i = 0; i < intKeys.length; i++)
    {
        Booking booking = bookingss.get(intKeys[i]);
        if (!booking.getMailing())
            mail = false;

        // Some updating done here on "booking"
        ...

        // Overwrite old map values with new ones
        bookings.put(intKeys[i], booking);
        mapFax.put(intKeys[i], booking);

    }

    // mail == false whenever at least one of the booking
    // stored in the map had their getMailing() method return false

    if (!mail)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < intKeys.length; j++)
        {
            // Updates AGAIN !
            Booking booking = mapFax.get(intKeys[j]);
            booking.setMailing(false);
            mapFax.put(intKeys[j], booking);
            reservations.put(intKeys[j], booking);
        }
    }

    session.setAttribute(SESSION_BOOKINGS, BOOKINGS);
    return mapFax;
}
```

Basically, what this aims to do (apart from updating other fields of the `Booking` objects and returning the `mapFax` map for further processing) is to set the mailing field at false for each and every one of the objects in `mapFax` if at least one has the value set at false.

What bugs me if the `for(){if(){}}` followed by `if(){for(){}}` and I was wondering if there was some way to render it more efficient and readable ?

Comment: Your posted code seems to be missing the important parts.  You have only a `for...if` combo, no `if...for`, and the thing you do in the `if` (set `mail=false`) is not used anywhere.

Comment: Sounds like a question for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sounds like your Java objects are not normalized if you have to go looping through the object map to set a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first look for the mail flag (breaking the loop once found) and then would do all the update all in one loop ...

something like this...

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < intKeys.length; i++)
{
    Booking booking = bookingss.get(intKeys[i]);
    if (!booking.getMailing())
    {
        mail = false;
        break;
     }
}
....
for (int i = 0; i < intKeys.length; i++)
{
    // Some updating done here on "booking"
    ...     
    if (!mail)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
  // Overwrite old map values with new ones
    bookings.put(intKeys[i], booking);
    mapFax.put(intKeys[i], booking);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<Integer, Reservation> CreerMapFax(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    String[] strKeys = request.getParameterValues("keys");
    Integer[] intKeys = new Integer[strKeys.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strKeys.length; i++) {
        intKeys[i] = Integer.parseInt(strKeys[i]);
    }

    boolean mail = true;

    Map<Integer, Booking> mapFax = new HashMap<Integer, Booking>();
    Map<Integer, Booking> bookings= (HashMap<Integer, Booking>) session.getAttribute(SESSION_BOOKINGS);

    for (Integer intKey : intKeys) {
        Booking booking = bookingss.get(intKey);
        if (!booking.getMailing()) {
            mail = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(Integer intKey : intKeys) {
        Booking booking = mapFax.get(intKey);
        mapFax.put(intKey, booking);
        if(!mail) {
            booking.setMailing(false);
            reservations.put(intKey, booking);
        }
    }

    session.setAttribute(SESSION_BOOKINGS, BOOKINGS);
    return mapFax;
}
```